# blender automatically add faces in object mode

Tags: modeling

I'm having some problem with blender, I was working on a sphere in edit mode but as soon as I turn to object mode some faces automatically reappear.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide us with the blend file?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can guess so far is that you have hidden the faces with <kbd>H</kbd> instead of deleting them. Go into Edit Mode and press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. The missing faces might appear.

Comment: Agree, another reason could be if he had a mirror modifier along Y, but in edit mode he would see the "shadow" of the mirrored side... this should not be the case...